# VS2017 15.8.1 - ServiceHub.RoslynCodeAnalysisService32.exe high CPU - CodeLens disabled

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, codelens

Even though full solution analysis and codelens is disabled, the process ServiceHub.RoslynCodeAnalysisService32.exe spikes on CPU usage during input. If I suspend the process through Windows Resource Monitor, VS input gets more responsive. What is this process doing? Is it possible to disable it?

Comment: I experience other problems with 15.8.1 and CPU usage. For me the main process takes 70% full time.